# Не устанавливаются cookies

Tags: php

Чисто академический класс, не пойму почему не ставится кука,  в var_dump  $_COOKIE['login'] выдаёт NULL.

```
 <?php
    class Auth
    {
      private $login;
      private $passwd;

      public function ath()
      {
        $this->login = md5('123');
        $this->passwd = md5('123');
        setcookie("login", $login, time()+3600*24, '/');
        setcookie("pass", $passwd, time()+3600*24,'/');
      }

    }

    /***********************/
    $m1 = new Auth();
    $m1 -> ath();

    ?>
```

Comment: `$login` и `$passwd` у вас не существует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пустые значение - удаляют куки, а не устанавливают её.
Вы перепутали переменные $this->login и $login, а также $this->passwd и $passwd

```
<?php
    class Auth
    {
      private $login;
      private $passwd;

      public function ath()
      {
        $this->login = md5('123');
        $this->passwd = md5('123');
        setcookie("login", $this->login, time()+3600*24, '/');
        setcookie("pass", $this->passwd, time()+3600*24,'/');
      }

    }

    /***********************/
    $m1 = new Auth();
    $m1 -> ath();

    ?>
```

Comment: Вы гений, спасибо! Никак не привыкну к ООП! (забыл использовать $this, чтобы обратится к соотв. полю)